# C++ linked list report function

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have created a memory manager program that uses nodes in a linked list that store the Job number of the node and the start and end byte of the memory used by the node.

I am having trouble thinking of a way to make my `report_jobs` function work. I would like the output to look like this

```
JOB         Memory Usage 

1           10 – 50 54 – 75 200 – 240 
5           1 – 9 101 – 134 
3           180 – 184 185 – 192
```

With the fact that multiple nodes could have the same job, I am having trouble figuring out how to loop through this so that it will only print the job once, but go through all the nodes and see if it has that job number, then print the start and end bytes.

Here is some sample code that i was messing with, im positive i am over complicating things and I just need to see it in a more simple way.

```
void report_jobs(void)
{
    ALLOCPTR t = alloclist;
    ALLOCPTR m = alloclist;
    int numberofnodes = 0;
    int job = 0;

while(m!=NULL)
{
 jobb++;

    while(t!=NULL)
    {
            if(t->id == job)
            {
                cout << t->id << t-> start_byte << t-> end_byte << endl;

            }
            t = t->next;


    }


   m = m->next

}
```

Comment: why not put these infomation in a dict and output

Comment: This is not totally trivial. You need to aggregate (sorted?) address ranges with respect to your jobs. You'll need some stuff under the hood for this to run well, depending on the use cases you expect. For example, if you have a lowish bound on the job ids you need to work with, you could make a struct that holds the start and end bytes and make an appropriately long vector of linked lists of this structure to organize the data. If the job ids go crazy, you could use a hash of linked lists of the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you want to do us use a hash table or index table keyed on the job id, and populate that entry with the start and end byte information as you iterate over your list.

Then, make another pass over the table to generate your output.

```
for (i in alloclist) {
    table[i->id].populate(i->start_byte, i->end_byte);
}

for (j in table) {
    std::cout << table[j];
}
```